# Divergence of the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2\ln x}$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to show that the following integral diverges:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2\ln x}$$

The integral has a problem at both endpoints so I understand that I have to split it into parts, for example, splitting it it between 1 to 2 and then again from 2 to $\infty$.

For the latter part, I can show that as $x$ goes from 2 to $\infty$ the integral converges. Particularly, $x^2\ln x>x^2$ and hence $\frac{1}{x^2\ln x}>\frac{1}{x^2}$, and $\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}$ converges.

Any help showing that $\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x^2\ln x}$ diverges would be much appreciated.

Comment: The denominator is linear near $x=1$, so that is where your issue is. The behavior as $x\to\infty$ is not an issue for convergence since the denominator is growing larger than $x^2$.

Comment: Substitution $u=lnx$ makes things cear immediately.

Answer (score 2):

It is only for $x\gt e$ that $x^2\ln x\gt x^2$. But if you want to look at the integral from $2$ to $\infty$, you can substitute the correct inequality $x^2\ln x\ge (\ln 2)x^2$ and reach the same conclusion.

So the integral from $2$ to $\infty$ converges. But the integral from $1$ to $2$ does not. To show this, note that $0\lt \ln(1+t)\le t$ in the interval $(0\lt t\le 1$. So in the interval $(1,2]$ we have $\frac{1}{x^2\ln x}\ge \frac{1}{4(x-1)}$, so by comparison $\int_1^2 \frac{1}{x^2\ln x}\,dx$ diverges.